# How to interact between geth and mist?

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-deployment

I know that mist is the gui of geth and geth represent the real node of client.

here i have a question is that:

when i use geth to construct a contract named greeter1,

then i type `eth.getCode(greeter1.address)` in web3 i can directly get the 
greeter1's address.

But when i use mist to construct a contract named greeter2,

then i use geth to type `eth.getCode(greeter2.address)`, i can't directly get the greeter2's address in web3.

I use var `"greeter2 = eth.contract(greeter2's abi).at(greeter2's contractaddress)"` in web3 then i can get the address.

Isn't the mist just a gui of geth?

Why i can't directly get the contract's address from geth after using mist contruct the contract?

Isn't the abi just used between node from node, why in the same node i should use abi?

please help to correct me, thank you all!